# How can map and reduce run in parllel

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a beginner to hadoop & when I am running a hadoop job I noticed the progress log which shows map 80% reduce 25%. My understanding of map reduce is that mappers produce bunch of intermediate values. After mappers producing output there is shuffle/sort of intermediate pairs & these values are sent to reduce job. Can someone please explain me how map/reduce can work in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outputs from the mappers have to be copied to the appropriate reducer nodes. This is called the shuffle process. That can start even before all the mappers have finished, since the decision of which key goes to which reducer is dependent only on the output key from the mapper. So the 25% progress you see is due to the shuffle phase.

After shuffle, there is a sort phase and then the reduce phase. Sort and reduce cannot happen unless all mappers have completed. Since shuffle can happen before the mappers finish, you can see a maximum of 33.33% reduce completion before the mappers have finished. This is because the default apache implementation considers shuffle, sort and reduce each to take an equal 33.33% of the time.

Comment: By setting `mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps` in `mapred-site.xml` you can control the proportion of the mappers (percentage) that need to be completed before any reducers can start.